# Qt: Multiple QScrollArea in the same parent widget

Tags: node.js, qt

I'm using nodegui(QT library for node) and I'm trying to create multiple vertical scroll areas but it doesn't work as expected.

```
import {QMainWindow, QWidget, FlexLayout,QScrollArea } from '@nodegui/nodegui';
const win = new QMainWindow();
win.setWindowTitle(`Test`);
win.setMinimumSize(900, 600);


const root = new QWidget()

const terminal1 = new QScrollArea()
terminal1.setInlineStyle(`width:100px`)
const div1 = new QWidget()
div1.setInlineStyle('width:1800px; height:100px; border: 1px solid yellow')
terminal1.setWidget(div1)

const terminal2 = new QScrollArea()
terminal2.setInlineStyle(`width:100px`)
const div2 = new QWidget()
div2.setInlineStyle('width:1800px; height:100px; border: 1px solid green')
terminal2.setWidget(div2)

const layout = new FlexLayout()
root.setLayout(layout)

layout.addWidget(terminal1)
layout.addWidget(terminal2)


win.setCentralWidget(root)

win.show();
(global as any).win = win;
```

Is any way to create stacked QScrollAreas?

Comment: Please show the *real* code -- preferably as a [mcve].  As it is, you have `root.setLayout(layout)` followed by `root.setLayout(layoutRoot)` where `layoutRoot` is empty.  Hence I'd expect your main window's central widget to be empty.

Comment: @G.M. There was 2 extra lines that I forgot to remove. I added the full code snippet.